# Force evaluation of recursive call in pattern match

Tags: recursion, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I am using match-lambda to rewrite certain functions in terms of more basic ones.  Here is an example that takes strings representing input code for let* calls and returns them as strings converted to nested unary lets:

```
(define let*→nested-unary-lets
  (match-lambda
   (`(let* (()) ,<exprs>)
   `(let () ,<exprs>))
   (`(let* ((,<var> ,<val>)) ,<exprs>)
   `(let ((,<var> ,<val>)) (let () ,<exprs>)))
   (`(let* ((,<var> ,<val>) . ,<clauses>) ,<exprs>)
   `(let ((,<var> ,<val>)) (let*→nested-unary-lets '(let* (,@<clauses>) ,<exprs>))))))
```

Here is an example of a call to let*→nested-unary-lets:

```
(let*→nested-unary-lets '(let* ((a 1) (b (+ a 1)) (c (+ a b))) (displayln c)))
'(let ((a 1))
   (let*→nested-unary-lets
    '(let* ((b (+ a 1)) (c (+ a b)))
       (displayln c))))
```

I was wondering if there is any way to force the evaluation of the recursive call to let*→nested-unary-lets so that the output string contains only nested lets and requries no further evaluation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using quasiquoting to output your answer in the recursive case, so just add a comma (`,`) before the recursive call to `let*->nested-unary-lets` (like the ones before `<var>` and `<val>`) so it is evaluated immediately.  The `,` in quasiquotes can splice in the result of any expression, not just variables.  The line:

```
`(let ((,<var> ,<val>)) (let*→nested-unary-lets '(let* (,@<clauses>) ,<exprs>)))
```

has some other problems as well: in order for the `,@` to work, the `'` before the inner `let*` needs to be `` ` ``.  Here is the version I suggest:

```
`(let ((,<var> ,<val>)) ,(let*→nested-unary-lets `(let* ,<clauses> . ,<exprs>)))
```

That requires that the match for `<exprs>` be changed to `. ,<exprs>` to allow more than one.

Comment: Many thanks!  It turns out it needed to be: ,(let*→nested-unary-lets `(let* (,@<clauses>) ,<exprs>)) -- but I never would have gotten there without your suggestions. :-)

Comment: @Schemer: I added the `.` before `,<exprs>` to allow more than one; if you are matching only one, you should not have the `.` in the quasiquoted output either.